# domain class constraint in entry creation

Tags: grails, constraints, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

In my Grails project I need to add a particular constraint to an entry of my domain class object.
Domain class is as follows:

```
class HealthServiceType {
   String healthService;
   static belongsTo = [doctor:Doctor]
   static constraints = {

   }

   static mapping = {

   }
}
```

I need that healthService is not empty and is unique for each Doctor; that is, I can have multiple "test" value for healthService, but each one need to have different Doctor value.

Is it possible to perform this constraint in domain class? Or do I need to implement some check in Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite simple to make a unique property. For example:

```
static constraints = {
  healthService(unique: ['doctor'])
}
```

The above will ensure that the value of `healthService` is unique for each value of `doctor` within your domain class.